# Extract Name and Surname and save in 2 different variables?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm having a slight problem, and its racking my nerves now! The question is:

Just say you have a name: "Jeremy Clarkson" , how can I just extract "Jeremy" out of that and save it in a variable?

This is what I've done:

```
String[]FirstName = Name.split(" ");
```

I have split it, but now how do i store these 2 words in 2 different variables

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] result = Name.split(" ");
String firstName = result[0];
```

Try to follow [Java naming convention](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) and change the variables names to begin with small letters.

Answer (score 2):

This really would take twenty seconds to look up...

```
String[] nameParts = Name.split(" ");
String firstName = nameParts[0];
String surname = nameParts[1];
```

You should not post to SO without trying your own homework first or you won't improve. Bear in mind that this will fail if there was only a single name for instance

Answer (score 2):

The result of the `split` will be a List containing both names, not just the first one, so `FirstName` is probably not the best name for the variable. :)  Also, regular variables should not be capitalized; that's for constants and class names.  Here's one way:

```
String[] names = fullName.split(" ");
String firstName = names[0];
String lastName = names[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] nameStrings = "Jeremy Clarkson".split(" ");
String firstName = nameStrings[0];  
String surName = nameStrings[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] names = Name.split(" ");
String firstName = names[0];
String lastName = names[1];
```

Check the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for information on how `split()` works.

Answer (score 1):

```
String name = "Jeremy Clarkson";
String[] names = name.split(" ");

String firstName = names[0];
String lastName = names[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you put values into an array, you can access each of the array's value and copy it into individual variable (to access it, use index):

```
String[]FirstName = Name.split(" ");
String value1 = FirstName[0];
String value2 = FirstName[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggest solutions will not work for 'Peter van Der Schyff' (Dutch/German surnames) where the surname is van Der Schyff, and the firstname is Peter.

```
String fullName = "Peter van Der Schyff";
String firstname = fullName.split(" ")[0];
String surname = fullname.substring(fullName.indexOf(' '));
```